# isDisplayed() method always returns true for some elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to test appearance of error message when input field is empty. Error message designed as a label to input element.
When the message is invisible, it has attribute *"display: none;"*.

When I find that message by text and call *isDisplayed()* method, it always returns true, even when message is invisible. I write tests on Java, so I have no *isVisible()* message.

I've tried method *getAttribute("style")*, but it returns empty string.
Method *getCssValue("display")* returns *"block"* even when on page it has value *"none"*.

I expected *ElementNotVisibleException* after calling *click()* method, but nothing happened!

Any ideas? Workarounds?

Here example of HTML:

`<form id="from id" style="display: block;">`

`<input id="input" name="input">`

`<label for="input" generated="true" style="display: none;">Error text here.</label>`

`</from>`

Comment: You simply find wrong element. Try to locate your element with css or xpath selectoor

Comment: I'm guessing your selector isn't selecting the right element (possibly an earlier element that matches the selector)

Comment: Share the exact HTML and code that reproduces this issue and explain what browser this is being tested against.

Comment: Found element is correct. There are only one element on the page with that text. I use Chrome for testing (can run on firefox/ie).

Comment: @user2796068 I belive it's wrong element because you say that it has `display: none;` in style attribute, and when you try to return that attribute with webdriver you get an empty string

Comment: Yes, I think, I found a problem... Searching by text finds element that contains this label. I'll try xpath...

Comment: Yes, thank you all! Now it is working! Petrovich, spasibo!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a WebDriverWait() to find the WebElement, and you can wait for the visibility of the element:

```
/**
 * 
 * Get a Web Element using WebDriverWait()
 * 
 */

public WebElement getInputBox() throws TimeoutException {

    WebElement webElement = null;
    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(5);

    // find an element using a By selector

    driverWait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#input")));

    webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#input"));

    return webElement;
}
```